# Cold Water Tap has High Pressure

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, water-pressure

Thanks for reading, I appreciate it.  In my main floor bathroom, my cold water sink tap has incredibly high pressure.  All other water sources in the house seem to have a normal operating pressure.  Even the tub in the same bathroom from the same line only feet away has normal pressure.

I swapped the hot and cold cartridges in the taps to see if the CW cartridge was the culprit. The CW cartridge worked fine in the HW tap.  With the HW cartridge in the CW tap, water was still blasting out.  Not a cartridge problem.

I do not have a pressure regulating valve on my main water line.....not sure I need one, pressure everywhere else seems fine.

I`m stumped.  thanks for your insight.

Comment: What do you mean by "incredibly high pressure" here?  Did you measure it with a gauge and found it to be 150 psi or is there just some symptoms that you are stating as "pressure"?

Comment: Hey jwh20, No I have not measured the pressure with a gauge.  If I open the shut off value to the tap all the way, the water that comes out of the tap so hard that it would redirect out of the sink and up onto the walls!! No kidding!

Comment: "I do not have a pressure regulating valve on my main water line" Sounds like you need one. How is the pressure at your other fixtures? Is this one the only one with an issue?

Comment: Is the question why? or how to deal with it? Close the supply valve partially  until you get the pressure you want.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is test your water pressure. Gauges are available at home supply stores or online for as little as $10. The gauge attaches to any hose bib in your home.
An ideal pressure range for a domestic water supply is about 60 to 70 psi. If it's much over 100 you should consider adding a pressure reducing valve (PRV) on your incoming water supply line. Excessively high pressure can result in leaks in your water lines or fixtures.
Different faucets in a home will often exhibit different water pressure based on a number of factors. In order to comply with state and federal guidelines newer ones have water restrictors in them. The faucet in question may be older (no restrictor) or it may have been removed at some point.
One solution is to simply replace the faucet.

[image]